# GNU grep on FreeBSD not working properly

Tags: linux, shell, grep, freebsd

I have a weird problem on FreeBSD 8.4-STABLE with grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD.

If I try to `grep -Hnr searchstring` I didn't get any output, but grep is running said ps aux and is keep running until I kill the process.

If I copy a testfile in an empty directory and do

`cat testfile | grep searchstring` it is working.

But if I try to
`grep -Hnr searchstring` in that directory I also get no output, grep keeps running and running but didn't produce any matches.

Anybody knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you gave `-r`, you still have to give grep a file argument. Othersize, as you've discovered, it just sits there waiting for input on stdin.

You want

```
grep -Hnr searchstring .
# ....................^^
```

That will recursively find files under the current directory.

Comment: Ah thanks, on the systems where I've already used this pattern it is somehow working without the dot. But it is working like you said, thank you.

Comment: GNU grep versions 2.11+ assume `.` when `-r` is used without any arguments. See the New features section [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2012-03/msg00000.html). I would guess the OP got used to that without realizing it.

Answer (score 1):

Though it doesn't seem to be documented, if you invoke `grep` with the `-r` option and no file or directory name arguments, it defaults to the current directory, almost as if you had typed `grep -R pattern .` except that `./` does not appear in the output.

Apparently this is a fairly new feature.

If you do a recursive `grep` in a directory with a lot of contents, it could simply take a long time -- perhaps forever if there are device files such as `/dev/zero` that can produce infinite output.